# Convert 18 decimal Julian Timestamp with Java

Tags: java, julian-date

I need to convert what I think is a Julian timestamp to a regular time stamp with Java.

The application that generates this timestamp is a proprietary payment system (Base24-EPS from ACI). I need to be able to pull and parse the value from the database with a Java application.

A sample timestamp value in decimal is 18 digits:

```
137955731472778910
```

With DALCI (internal tool provided by Base24-EPS), I can see this is equivalent of:

```
3: convert 137955731472778910 to datetime(yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss);
2019/12/14 12:39:07
```

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059172/convert-julian-timestamp-to-regular-time-in-unix) which seems to be related. But *137955731472778910* is smaller than *210866803200000000*, which is the Julian timestamp for 01-JAN-1970 (epoch for unix time).

All the other Julian timestamp online converter I see, for example http://www.onlineconversion.com/julian_date.htm, have Julian date format as double *2458806.52903*.

18 digits seem too long.

Do you know how can I parse this timestamp format with Java?

Many thanks.

Comment: 137955731472778910 converts to ‭1EA1E01C12A069E‬ in hex, 15 letters. So the internal DB column width is probably 8 bytes (16 letters meaning 13795... has a "leading zero" while stored and not shown in display, but necessary for conversions)

Comment: Yes the internal DB column is RAW (8) in Oracle. Decimal 137955731472778910 
 is 01EA1E01C12A069E in hex string.

Comment: Assuming that the conversion is linear, you need to convert at least 2 timestamps to a known format and show us.

Comment: Don't you have some documentation for these tools supplying the data?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt just try another one *137934280958694210* represents *2019/11/19 16:48:15*.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have very limited access to its documentation, will try to get a bit more information from the vendor, just fire another inquiry to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are in the UTC timezone (you probably aren't, but you haven't told me what timezone you are in), I have a formula:

```
long timestampFromAci = ...;
long timestampJava = (timestamp - 122192460002790000L) / 10000;

Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestampJava);
new Date(timestampJava); // Old, deprecated - use java.time classes
```

This assumes that the conversion is linear.

Your product timestamp has 10000 units per millisecond, since there are 2145052000 milliseconds between 2019/11/19 16:48:15 and 2019/12/14 12:39:07, and the difference in your product's timestamp is 21450514084700.

If you divide these two, that's almost exactly 10000 - the difference is because your tool doesn't display fractional seconds.

Extrapolating from that, I can derive that value that your product timestamp would have for the Unix epoch op 1/1/1970 - 122192460002790000.

However, as I said, I made the assumption that you are in the UTC timezone. For every hour that your timezone is off from UTC, you need to adjust that number by 3600 seconds times 10,000,000 units product timestamp units per second.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful.